# Orbit-Stabilizer theorem example

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

I have a group $G$ defined by $\langle x,y \mid x^3=y^4=1, yx=x^2y\rangle $ and a left action defined by conjucation.

I have calculated the orbits to be $G.1 = [1] $ $G.x=[x,x^2]$ $G.y=[y, xy, x^2y]$ $G.y^2=[y^2, xy^2, x^2y^2]$ and $G.y^3 = [y^3, xy^3,x^2y^3] $

However, when calculating the stabilizer subgroups of $x$ and $y$ I get $Gx=[1,x,x^2]$ and $Gy=[1,y,y^2,y^3]$

The orbit of $y$ and its stabilizer subgroup follow the orbit stabilizer theorem as multiplying their order we get $12$ which is the order of the group $G$.

But using $x$ we get $2\times  3 = 6$ instead of $12$.

What am I missing?

Comment: How do you know the group has order $12$?

Comment: I counted the elements in the different orbits, and as two orbits are either equal or distinct, then there should be 12 elements in total

Comment: What's the action?  Left multiplication?

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot to mention, the action is conjucation

Comment: I think you miscomputed: $y^2$ is in the center, and  the stabilizer of $x$ is generated by $x$ and $y^2$ (it has order 6 then).

Comment: It is easier if you write down that $y^mx=x^{2^m}y^m$ ($m\neq 0$) and therefore $x^ny^m\cdot x\cdot (y^{-m}x^{-n})=x^{2^m}$. Thus, solving $2^m\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ gives you the orbit $G_x=\{x^ny^{2k}:k=0, 1, n=0,1,2\}$.

Comment: Ah, yes I see it now, thank you!